# CustomValidator "OnServerValidate" event automatically firing when file selected through AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0, asyncfileupload

I am working on asp.net web form where I am using `CustomValidator` with server side validation event `OnServerValidate` to validate some stuff of page 
and also using ajax `AsyncFileUpload` control to upload the file.

the both controls `CustomValidator` and `AsyncFileUpload` are independent on page there are no relation between both, but when I select any file in  `AsyncFileUpload` the server side validation event of CustomValidator automatically firing which causing issue. the custom validator validation method should only fire when I click on their respective submit button which is working correctly but in addition `CustomValidator` `OnServerValidate` method also firing by `AsyncFileUpload` on file selection.

fallowing is the sample code I have created to demonstrate the issue.

ASPX Code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <%-- <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUpdateSplitedExposure" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>--%>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvValidateSplitExposureSumByServer" Display="None"
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="" OnServerValidate="cvValidateSplitExposureSumByServer_ValidateSplitExposureSum" ControlToValidate="txttmpValidateSum" ValidateEmptyText="true"
            ValidationGroup="UpdateExposure"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttmpValidateSum" Style="display: none; width: 0px" ValidationGroup="UpdateExposure"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="imgBtnUpdateSplitedExposure" runat="server" ToolTip="OK"
            Text="OK" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="UpdateExposure" Enabled="true" />
        <%--   </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>

        <%-- <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUploadPayRoll" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>--%>
        <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="asyncPayRollUploader" runat="server" CompleteBackColor="White"
            Width="400px" EnableViewState="false" />
        <asp:Button ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ToolTip="OK"
            Text="OK" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="NEWG" Enabled="true" />
        <%-- </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
    </div>
</form>
```

VB

```
Partial Class AsyncUpload
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub cvValidateSplitExposureSumByServer_ValidateSplitExposureSum(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)

    Try

        args.IsValid = False

    Catch ex As Exception

        args.IsValid = False

    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub asyncPayRollUploader_UploadedComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles asyncPayRollUploader.UploadedComplete

End Sub


Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click

End Sub

Protected Sub imgBtnUpdateSplitedExposure_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imgBtnUpdateSplitedExposure.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Can any one help me please?